# How to display the extjs chart and the extjs grid in one page

Tags: extjs, salesforce

In my requirement I have to display the pie chart and the grid panel which should show the statistics data when we click on the commandlink. So I have developed the pie chart in 4.0.7 version and the grid panel which show data is 3.1.1 and i shown a command link above the chart when i click on the link the grid with the data have to show in the same page. but when i click on the link the grid with data is not showing. In error console i am getting ext_all.js is not supported is showing.

Comment: You might want to include exact error message and at least some of your code - otherwise nobody would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce uses extJS3 for some of their own stuff and if your page uses factory sidebar, etc, then you need to use extJS4 in sandbox mode. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364033/what-is-an-extjs-sandbox)