# Is it possible to use two different ExtJS versions in the project?

Tags: php, extjs, versions

im doing on some project which mainly runs on ExtJS version 3.4. Now the question is, if I can use ExtJS version 4.x in the same project?

For example I would need xtype: image from 4.x version to display image.
Note that I would use 4.x version in new file.

tnx for furture assistance!

Comment: yes its possible. use ext-all-sandbox.js

Comment: Tnx a lot, I will google it a bit more :P

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364033/what-is-an-extjs-sandbox