# ExtJs and ExtReact in the same project

Tags: reactjs, extjs, extreact

I've been googling for a while, unsuccessfully, if it is possible to use ExtJS on a React Project or use ExtReact components on a ExtJS Project.

What I need to know is if ExtJS and ExtReact can coexist and been integrated in the very same project and make them to interact and share info, cookies, data, sessions, whatever, between each other.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but to have two versions of ExtJS run next to each other, you can switch to ["Ext Sandbox"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364033/what-is-an-extjs-sandbox). I think if you want to have ExtJS and ExtReact run next to each other, that should work as well.

Comment: Ok @Alexander, I'll take a look at Ext Sandbox